# Updating Deployments SCCM

Tags: deployment, sccm

I'm super new to SCCM and trying out some stuff.
Atm I create a lot of Applications to deploy on around 50 Clients.
Before I deploy them to all clients I test them on a test Client.
The problem now is that if I change sth in the Deployment Type like the installation command I have to delete the deployment everytime afterwards and deploy it again or the change wont happen on the client when I install the Application next time.

There probaly a way easier method which I can't figure out atm.
So how do i update the changes I made after the Application is allready deployed?

Greetings,
Paxz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get an answer from microsofts technet forum.

For deployments to know the update in the command line, I just have to push the next policy polling cycle.
This will only be effective for clients that haven't executed the deployment type yet.

Other than that there seems to be no other way than deleting the deployment and re-deploying it for the changes to be known for the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The application deployment command line will only be executed if the application is not detected - i.e. the Application Detection criteria evaluates to false.  With this premise, it is possible to change the Application Detection criteria so it evaluates to false... perhaps add an addition rule to include "file1.txt exists"?  This should work, but it is ugly and I would not recommend it.

**A better approach**

I prefer to test my application deployments on VMs in the first instance: prepare the destination machine, snapshot it, then deploy.

If you need to tweak your deployment you can then make the required changes, redistribute the content (if required), then restore the VM's snapshot for a fresh deployment.

Comment: Ok seems like i got the question wrong, my intention is too let the Deployment see the changes i made in the deployment command without redeploying it. So when I changed the deployment code it should use the new code from the command line instead of the old one when redeploying it.
Using a VM wouldnt be necessary since i can simply uninstall the Application and install it again. When I install it again it should see if I made changes in the Commandline.
Hope this explains it better.

Comment: Your message is still not clear.

I would suggest you take a look at "C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\AppEnforce.log" and "C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\AppEval.log" to see what the client is doing.

These logs will how you the commands used by the client.  Note: you may need to reboot/update the client policy to obtain the latest version of the modified deployment.

Comment: I actually got an answer out of the technet Forum but thx for the effort.